# What's the best way to find out the constraints on a IBMi DB2400 table from a java program?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I need a way for my java layer to inspect what constraints exist for all files/tables within a particular library (on an IBMi/iSeries/System-i/AS400 system).  I know that I can query the SYSIBM.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS view to find out, but is this a legitimate and safe way to go about it?  Is there a better way?

It would be preferable if it could be done with Sql using the com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver jdbc driver.  But I am open to other suggestions.

**Note:** answers not pertaining to DB2400 on the IBMi platform are not useful here.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the native driver instead of the one in jt400.jar?

Comment: Good question Thorbjørn.  The reason is so that we can have the SQL run under the JOB's user, authority, etc. instead of having to provide separate authentication information.  From my understanding jt400.jar requires that user and password be specified...

Comment: +1 just for asking an IBMi question.

Comment: for local connections you can use *CURRENT, *CURRENT as credentials.  It does a network connection though, I do not know if the native driver does that.  I have not done much SQL work so I don't know if either driver can do what you want though.

Comment: IBM actually removed the *CURRENT/*CURRENT support a while back for unstated security reasons.

Comment: Though standard use of *CURRENT/*CURRENT was removed, a temporary workaround was also provided that allows *CURRENT/*CURRENT to continue to be used for an additional couple of releases. Also, while the specific "*CURRENT"/"*CURRENT" values will no longer be valid, replacement special values can give the same results. See [UNABLE TO CONNECT AS CURRENT USER](http://www-912.ibm.com/n_dir/nas4apar.NSF/c79815e083182fec862564c00079d117/8ef5d02184146cc3862575170041eeb5?OpenDocument) for one discussion and method for handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is legit and safe to query that table.  There are some possible system API calls or commands you could use with a SQL UDF but it's not worth doing over a query on that table.

Comment: I've moved forward assuming this is the correct answer, so I'll call yours the answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that this is the ANS and ISO standard catalog table.  There is also a QSYS2.SYSCST table which is an iSeries specific format (not portable or standard) that could also be queried for the same information.